# Cannot open include file: 'qrencode.h': No such file or directory (building libqrencode on Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cygwin, libraries

I'm using the qrencode library in my Qt project on OS X after installing it without any issues, but now I need to install it on Windows and I have no idea how to go about doing that. I've looked around for a while now, and here's what I know (or atleast think I know) :

I need to use Cygwin to install it on my computer. I believe I have to use --prefix on the ./configure in order to install it to the right place. The issue is that I have no idea where that place is.

Here is the library's website, in case that could help: http://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/

Could someone help me with this please? I realize this is probably really simple but I am not really used to any of this...

**[Edit]**
Well, after removing the library, cleaning and rebuilding everything, I'm now facing the following issue: `LNK1104: cannot open file 'qrencode.lib'` Any idea of what could be wrong? :/

Comment: How are you building this project?  What does the #include directive say exactly? Have you added the folder that contains that .h file to your PATH, and/or what other mechanism are you using to set include folders?

Answer (score 1):

You can build library in any directory. Just add it's path to project file (`.pro`) in `INCLUDEPATH` section.

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/dev/libs/libqrencode/
```

`C:/dev/libs/libqrencode/` is sample path, replace it with your own. `qrencode.h` must be in this directory.

If you are using the same `.pro` file to build on both Windows and OS X just do like this:

```
win32 {
    INCLUDEPATH += C:/dev/libs/libqrencode/
}
```

Comment: Well, after removing the library, cleaning and rebuilding everything, I'm now facing the following issue:  
` LNK1104: cannot open file 'qrencode.lib' `
Any idea of what could be wrong? :/

Comment: `LIBS += "C:/dev/libs/libqrencode/build/lib/qrencode.lib"` where "_C:/dev/libs/libqrencode/build/lib/_" is path to _qrencode.lib_ file.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a qrencode.lib file. In the 'lib' folder, there is 'libqrencode.a' and 'libqrencode.la', but no '.lib' file anywhere. Have I done something wrong when building the library?

Comment: The same error still occurs (LNK1104: cannot open file 'qrencode.lib'), even when using adding the library as you suggested. :/